RLS Does Not Bind Queries to List Partitioned Partitions
Each table in this database is partitioned with a column named SourceId, list partitioned such that SourceId= 'COKE' or 'PEPSI', etc.
RLS(Row Level Security) is being used such that each user will be 'COKE', 'PEPSI, etc. and that the user_name() is used to determine access to data in each table's security predicate.
The thought was that the RLS security predicate would force each query to be bound to a single partition, however, this turned out not to be the case.
All query plans are showing that every partition is being scanned. This seems to be because the RLS function is being applied as a row filter after the data has been fetched from the tables. Or in other cases, it is non-deterministic, therefore the partition can't be determined in the query plan.
CREATE SECURITY POLICY [dbo].[u_tblGLScheduledTransactionsFilter] 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE [dbo].[fn_SP_DatabaseName]([SourceID]) ON [dbo].[u_tblGLScheduledTransactions]
WITH (STATE = ON, SCHEMABINDING = ON)
GO

TVF used for RLS Security Policies
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SP_DatabaseName](@SourceID AS Nvarchar(4000))
    RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS fn_SP_DatabaseName_output
    -- Predicate logic
    WHERE(CONVERT(Nvarchar(4000),USER_NAME()) = @SourceID)
    or  (CONVERT(Nvarchar(4000),USER_NAME()) = 'admin')
GO

To get around this, the tables have been converted to view in such a way that each physical table has been renamed and a view has been created with the original table name.
For example:

tblContact is renamed to u_tblContact
View created named tblContact (see below)

This allows all existing sql calls to function and also binds each table and joined table to a single partition.
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[tblContact] AS  
--This will allow all non admin calls to be bound to a single partition
SELECT * FROM [u_tblContact] WHERE SourceID = user_name()
GO

The problem with that is we are losing performance in some cases with queries that return many columns and having many joins (only when using views encapsulating tables though). There is no noticeable time difference between using tables the view encapsulation for smaller queries having just a few columns and joins.
Are there any other ways to force RLS to make use of the associated partition using user_name() or any tricks so we don't have to pass all queries through hacked out views?
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM u_tblGLScheduledTransactions


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblGLScheduledTransactions


Paste the plan posted.
The first query calls the physical table and relies on RLS to filter the results. All partitions are read.
The second query calls the view, which places the partition value directly in the where clause. Still uses RLS but only one partition is read.
I think it has something to do with how the seek predicates are formulated.
Tables structure semantics
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[u_tblGLScheduledTransactions]
(
      [GLScheduledTransactionID] INT NOT NULL
       ...  
    , [SourceID] NVARCHAR(4000) NOT NULL
    , CONSTRAINT [PK_tblGLScheduledTransactions] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED([GLScheduledTransactionID] ASC , [SourceID] ASC) ON psSourceID(SourceID)
    , CONSTRAINT [CIX_tblGLScheduledTransactions] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([SourceID] ASC, [GLScheduledTransactionID] ASC) ON psSourceID(SourceID)
)
ON psSourceID(SourceID)
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[u_tblGLScheduledTransactions] SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = AUTO)
GO


Partitioning isn't meant to improve this kind of performance. Unless you have an actual use case for Partitioning, I would recommend getting rid of it (it can actually hurt performance too). To get help with your index performance, you would have to provide the index definitions, the table definitions, the query, and its actual execution plan (which you can upload to Paste The Plan and link in your post).

Hi @J.D - Thanks for the reply. I have updated my question This is a many -->1 replication scenario. The on-premises data comes from a multi-tenant system replicated to the cloud into one larger reporting system. Database restores in all environments at the source require the truncation of large swaths of data in seconds. Also, partitioning allows staging of large client exports more efficiently. The partitioning is Mainly for maintenance and moving data around efficiently.

Not sure I fully follow your description of your use cases for Partitioning, but if you're using the Replication feature of SQL Server, you can use filters to replicate only the data you actually need. In any case, is your use case really only just a SELECT COUNT(*) against the table? If so, that's easily optimized with a columnstore index. If the goal of RLS was only for performance reasons and not actually data security, then I would recommend scrapping that as well.

@J.D RLS is for security and compliance and a transparent way for client apps to query data with ease based on the sql login.

Cool beans. Thanks for adding your RLS policy definition to your Post. FWIW, using the system function USER_NAME() may invalidate it from being inlinable (I don't recall) and result in the function being called RBAR. But anyway, is your use case that you're trying to optimize for really only just a SELECT COUNT(*) against the table?

@J.D - No problem. There is a performance issue. There are some very large views with ~12-20 table joins, that when called using the LEFT JOIN tblTableName (views)semantics takes over a minute, however when using the INNER JOIN u_tblTableName (tables) semantics takes only 20 seconds. I think the large query with many joins that are using nothing but views encapsulating tables is taking a hit performance wise and I am guessing indexes are not able to be used to the to the fullest extent possible

"I am guessing indexes are not able to be used to the to the fullest extent possible" - ‍♂️ anything's possible. But would need to see the query for one of those views and its execution plan to be able to advise on that. As long as your predicates aren't too crazy, it shouldn't matter much how many joins are going on. But I'm sure regardless there's a way to improve even the 20s runtime possibly, let alone the > 1 minute runtime.
